# How to get a group ordered by the count column

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

It is hard to ask the question in plain english so I'll show what I'm trying to do.

Here's my SQL code:

```
select top 100 [Name], COUNT([Name]) as total from ActivityLog  
where [Timestamp] between '2010-10-28' and '2010-10-29 17:00'  
group by [Name]  
order by total desc
```

I need to write that in LinQ. So far I have the following:

```
var groups = from ActivityLog log in ctx.ActivityLog
 where log.Timestamp > dateFrom
 where log.Timestamp <= dateTo
 group log by log.Name;
```

but I don't have the `COUNT(*)` column to sort from :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[diceguyd30's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070032/how-to-get-a-group-ordered-by-the-count-column/4070282#4070282) technically is LINQ and is correct. In fact, the query syntax gets translated to those Queryable/Enumerable methods by the compiler. That said what's missing is using the [`group ... by ... into` syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386922.aspx). The equivalent query should be close to this:

```
var query = from log in ctx.ActivityLog
            where log.TimeStamp > dateFrom && log.TimeStamp <= dateTo
            group log by log.Name into grouping
            orderby grouping.Count() descending
            select new { Name = grouping.Key, Total = grouping.Count() };

var result = query.Take(100);
```

Note that in C# the `Take(100)` method has no equivalent in query syntax so you must use the extension method. VB.NET, on the other hand, does support `Take` and `Skip` in query syntax.

Comment: Ahhhh....I learned something new today!  +1 Thank you, query syntax is truly not my forte.

Comment: +1, me too... didn't know the 'into' keyword of the groupby syntax

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid I am far more comfortable with the fluent syntax (as opposed to query syntax), but here is one possible LINQ answer:

```
 ctx.ActivityLog
   .Where(x => x.TimeStamp > dateFrom && x.TimeStamp <= dateTo)
  .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
  .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Total = x.Count() })
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Total)
  .Take(100)
```

EDIT:

Alright, I stepped out of my comfort zone and came up with a query syntax version, just don't expect too much.  I warned you about my abilities above:

```
(from y in (
    from x in (
        from log in ActivityLog
        where log.Timestamp > dateFrom
        where log.Timestamp <= dateTo
        group log by log.Name)
    select new { Name = x.Key, Total = x.Count() })
orderby y.Total descending
select new { Name = y.Name, Total = y.Total }).Take(100)
```

Comment: +1, great tip, thanks... let's see if someone can figure it out with LinQ

Comment: +1 for the proper translation to LINQ. @sebastian this is technically LINQ and **query syntax** is compiled into the **fluent syntax**.