# LINQ Join Errors

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, join

I'm getting the following error:

```
The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.
```

when using the code below

```
var ccrCodes = (from c in db.CCRCodes
               join i in items on
                new { c.baan_cat_fam_code, c.baan_cat_code } equals
                new { i.baan_cat_family_code, i.baan_cat_code }
               where i => i.contact_dt.Value.Year == date.Year && i.contact_dt.Value.Month == date.Month
               select c).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.code_desc);
```

What I'm trying to do in LINQ is create a multi-condition join and am running into problems.  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment below, you might be interested in using the SelectMany approach to performing joins in LINQ to SQL. It should simplify things for you. See [When to prefer joins expressed with SelectMany() over joins expressed with the join keyword in Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4025871/59111).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving names to the properties in your anonymous objects:

```
var ccrCodes = (from c in db.CCRCodes
               join i in items on
                new { FamCode = c.baan_cat_fam_code, CatCode = c.baan_cat_code } equals
                new { FamCode = i.baan_cat_family_code, CatCode = i.baan_cat_code }
               where i => i.contact_dt.Value.Year == date.Year && i.contact_dt.Value.Month == date.Month
               select c).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.code_desc);
```

EDIT:  Alright, I have to confess, I am no expert on query syntax, but you want to filter the 'items' list before doing the join, like the following fluent version of your query:

```
db.CCRCodes
    .Join(
        items.Where(i => i.contact_dt.Value.Year == date.Year && i.contact_dt.Value.Month == date.Month),
        x => new { FamCode = x.baan_cat_fam_code, CatCode = x.baan_cat_code },
        x => new { FamCode = x.baan_cat_family_code, CatCode = x.baan_cat_code },
        (o,i) => o
    ).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.code_desc)
```

ANOTHER EDIT:  Per Ahmad's suggestion:

```
var ccrCodes = (from c in db.CCRCodes
                   join i in items.Where(x => x.contact_dt.Value.Year == date.Year && x.contact_dt.Value.Month == date.Month) on
                    new { FamCode = c.baan_cat_fam_code, CatCode = c.baan_cat_code } equals
                    new { FamCode = i.baan_cat_family_code, CatCode = i.baan_cat_code }
                   select c).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.code_desc);
```

YET ANOTHER EDIT: Per another Ahmad suggestion:

```
var ccrCodes = (from c in db.CCRCodes
                from i in items
                where i.contact_dt.Value.Year == date.Year && i.contact_dt.Value.Month == date.Month 
                  && c.baan_cat_fam_code == i.baan_cat_family_code && c.baan_cat_code == i.baan_cat_code
                select c).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.code_desc);
```

Comment: Nope, sorry. I get the following errors:  1) A local variable named 'i' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'i', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.  2) Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type/

Comment: See edit, you are declaring another variable called 'i' in your 'where' which is causing a majority of those errors.

Comment: Try moving the `where` clause up to the `items` usage: `join i in items.Where(o => o.contact_dt.Value.Year == date.Year && o.contact_dt.Value.Month == date.Month) ...`. The `i` is not in scope past the `join`, but `c` is in scope for usage. EDIT: just noticed your fluent syntax, same idea for the query syntax about `Where` placement.

Comment: @Ahmad, your comment helped me realize I could just mix and match some query and fluent syntax for this solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely! Keeping it in query syntax is possible but the query will get messy real quick. It would be `join i in (from o in items where ...) ...` so mixing it is much nicer looking. If a query syntax is desired for that I would move it to a separate var declaration at best, or use a [`let` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx).

Comment: BTW, doing a join on multiple keys in LINQ to SQL is probably even easier than using all those `new { ... }` declarations. A `SelectMany` can be used to perform an equi-join in LINQ to SQL and you'll have access to the `i` variable in that case. By `SelectMany` I mean doing a `from x in source1 from y in source2 where x.prop1 == y.prop1 && x.prop2 == y.prop2 select new { x, y }`. Take a look at this question for more info: [When to prefer joins expressed with SelectMany() over joins expressed with the join keyword in Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4025871/59111).

Comment: @Ahmad, that is very interesting!  I have added a version of that to my answer.  Is what I have there correct?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. Personally I would get rid of the fluent syntax in that particular usage and keep all the `where` logic together now that we have avoided the earlier join syntax limitation, but nonetheless it works and people have different preferences :) As I [mentioned yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070032/), it all compiles to the same thing ultimately and it's just a matter of readability.

Comment: Indeed, you have been adamantly teaching me the wonders of query syntax these last couple of days.  Thanks!  I removed the fluent syntax (though at this point I'm thinking you should just add my final answer as your very own answer so you can get the proper credit for it!) ^_^

Comment: I made a minor edit to implement the syntax I was referring to. As for credit, that's ok. I wouldn't want to do that twice in a row, especially since you were very close, so I figured I would chip in and let you improve on what you had :)